# Less style sheet language: prevent parentheses from being omitted in compiled CSS

Tags: css, less, transform

I'm using {less} and ran into a problem with using parenthesis. I wrote a mixin for a CSS3 transform property. I can't figure out how to have a parenthesis in the compiled CSS. Less sees the parentheses as an operation and omits them.

Original CSS:

```
   .plus {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg); }
```

Less mixin I wrote:

```
    .transform (@action, @value){
        -webkit-transform: @action(@value);
        -moz-transform: @action(@value);
        -o-transform: @action(@value); }
```

And the compiled CSS that results:

```
   .plus {
      -webkit-transform: rotate 45deg;
      -moz-transform: rotate 45deg;
     -o-transform: rotate 45deg; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just keep it as one value and pass in whatever you need when you are calling it.

```
.transform(@value) {
    -webkit-transform: @arguments;
    -moz-transform: @arguments;
    transform: @arguments;
}

.plus {
    .transform(rotate(45deg));
    .transform(scale(1.5, 2.0));
}
```

compiles to

```
.plus {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5, 2);
    transform: scale(1.5, 2);
}
```

Comment: this works. I'm still trying to wrap my head around arguments and the rest of less. I'm not a programmer so it's been making me feel stupid. thanks

Comment: Using `@arguments` variable is just an easy way to pass in all the arguments from the mixin. In my example it's not really necessary since there is only one, you could just call in the `@value` variable as well.

Answer (score 4):

Change your mixin to something like this (the key is building it into a string and then using an escaped value):

```
.transform (@action, @value){
  @escapedValue: ~"@{action}(@{value})";
  -webkit-transform: @escapedValue;
     -moz-transform: @escapedValue;
       -o-transform: @escapedValue; 
}
```